# Can not print pdf using wkhtmltopdf on mac

Tags: php, macos, ubuntu, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf library in my code-igniter application for printing. I'm using vagrant ubuntu on mac.

Url is like

```
> http://localhost:8084/{sitename}/{controller_name}/{function}
```

Code snippet is

```
> $pdf = new WKPDF();
>     // Set PDF's HTML
>     $html_in_string = "<html><body>Content goes here</body></html>";
>     $pdf->set_html($html_in_string);
>     // Convert HTML to PDF
>     $pdf->render();
>     // Output PDF. The file name is suggested to the browser.
>     $pdf->output(WKPDF::$PDF_EMBEDDED, 'print_file_name.pdf');
```

But it shows "Failed to load PDF document."

PDF document is not created in cache/temp.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: which version you are using of wkhtmltopdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove port from the url;

```
http://localhost/{sitename}/{controller_name}/{function}
```

i hope that will fix the issue;

Comment: I can not access this URL without using port. I've installed virtual machine to access server via vagrant.

Changing wkhtmltopdf library from 
$GLOBALS['WKPDF_BASE_SITE']=$protocol . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ':'. $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']  . $CFG->config["base_url"] . "/";
to
$GLOBALS['WKPDF_BASE_SITE']=$protocol . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ':'  . $CFG->config["base_url"] . "/";
resolved the issue.
Thanks

Comment: actually you are trying to access localhost from inside vagrant; so you don't need port; please change $GLOBALS['WKPDF_BASE_SITE'] as $GLOBALS['WKPDF_BASE_SITE']=$protocol . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $CFG->config["base_url"] . "/";

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be great to check directly from `console` either your `wkhtmltopdf` working though `commands`.

e.g.

```
"/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf path-to-html-file path-to-pdf-file
```

then you can confirm either lib is installed properly or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and then install correct version of wkhtmltopdf depending on your operating system:
https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html